# Android Marshmallow broadcastreceiver receiving multiple broadcasts for each send

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

My application has a subclass broadcast receiver:

```
   public class LocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    LocationBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_LOCATION_ACTION)) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BCAST LAT = " + extras.getDouble("LAT") + " LON = " + extras.getDouble("LON"));
            }
}
```

Generate a log message in the service that sends the broadcast and the log message above.  Getting multiple broadcasts for a single broadcast message sent.

I am dynamically registering the receiver using the following:

```
mLocateBcast = new LocationBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter locationFilter = new IntentFilter();
        locationFilter.addAction(Constants.BROADCAST_LOCATION_ACTION);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mLocateBcast,locationFilter);
```

I do not have a receiver defined in my manifest.  In previous Android versions I received a single broadcast for a similar setup.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you are registering several receivers.

Comment: Checked for multiple registrations in the code based on posts here.  Only register one time.

Comment: You do not show your code where you are using `LocalBroadcastManager` to send the broadcast. I assume that you are using `sendBroadcast()`. If so, and your code supports it thread-wise, temporarily switch to `sendBroadcastSync()`, then set a breakpoint in your `onReceive()` method. You will see both the code sending the broadcast and the code receiving the broadcast, and you will be able to determine which side is getting invoked more times than is appropriate. For example, you will be able to see if you have more than one `LocationBroadcastReceiver` registered.

Comment: Added logging that shows the constructor for the class containing my overrided onLocationChanged method is only called a single time.  My logs show a maximum of 5 times onLocationChanged was called with the same latitude and longitude values.  This does not occur for every location change so am ruling out multiple instances registering for the callback.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't just getting the same latitude and longitude values several times in rapid succession from Android? The "not for every location change" part sounds like the duplication is coming from upstream.

Comment: according to the logcat timestamps, the duplicate, 5 in a row, onLocationChanges are coming in the same millisecond.  This burst  happens when the required time between intervals expires.

Answer (score 0):

With Marshmallow, the onLocationChanged callback is called when the LocationRequest setInterval value expires regardless of whether there has been an actual location change.

Was not expecting this behavior.